# edit to substr and strpos causes Error 500

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I'm trying to make some edits to a piece of code but I get an error 500 when I do.
For this example, lets say that

```
basename(__FILE__)
```

is my_filename.php

The code is:

```
$HTTP_GET_VARS['feed_file'] = $_GET['feed_file'] 
= substr(
            basename(__FILE__),
            3,
            strpos( basename(__FILE__), '.php') -3
        );
```

$HTTP_GET_VARS['feed_file'] would echo as "filename"

Now, if

```
basename(__FILE__)
```

is aaa_filename.php
the original code would give $HTTP_GET_VARS['feed_file'] as "_filename"

I changed the code to

```
$HTTP_GET_VARS['export_feed'] = $_GET['export_feed'] 
= substr(
            basename(__FILE__),
            4,
            strpos( basename(__FILE__), '.php') -3
        );
```

$HTTP_GET_VARS['export_feed']now echos as "filename."

Ok, so I need to lose one more character from the end of the string. I change the -3 to -4 so that I have

```
$HTTP_GET_VARS['export_feed'] = $_GET['export_feed'] 
= substr(
            basename(__FILE__),
            4,
            strpos( basename(__FILE__), '.php') -4
        );
```

Only now the Error 500 is thrown.
Confusing the hell out of me as I thought it was going to be a simple change. Any suggestions on why I'm having problems simply changing the number of chars to drop from the beginning and end of a string?

Comment: What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php? (I also cant reproduce the issue you are getting https://3v4l.org/ZnJkn.

Comment: `$HTTP_GET_VARS`? What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: An what do you want to achive? I think there are better ways to get a part from a file name.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Already checked. Nothing logged in Apache logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `preg_match` to dynamically get "*filename*":

```
$basename = 'ab_filename.php';

if(preg_match('/_(.+)\.php$/',$basename,$matches)):
    $name = $matches[1]; // 'filename'
endif;
```

Now `$name` is just "*filename*"

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d3e4319b0c2d82607a4c2837da9711a38a3b7f9)

That aside, the code snippet you shared by itself would not cause a 500 server error. There is probably a domino effect and the error gets triggered elsewhere. Learn how to look up error logs for details.

Finally, if you'll keep using your current approach, don't hardcode the offset (your `-3` or `-4`). Rather compute it dynamically like so:

```
$basename = 'abcd_filename.php';

$pos_ = strpos($basename,'_') + 1;
$len  = strpos( $basename, '.php') - $pos_;
$name = substr($basename, $pos_, $len);
```

Now `$name` is "*filename*"